# Создание рекуррентной нейронной сети на scikit-learn

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, scikit-learn

Возможно ли при помощи scikit-learn создать рекуррентную нейронную сеть (RNN)?
Если да, то попрошу ссылку на материал.

Comment: А почему именно при помощи `scikit-learn`? Может стоит взглянуть в сторону `TensorFlow` и `Keras`?

Comment: @MaxU я думал что на scikit-learn можно реализовать все что связанно с машинным обучением, прочитал пару книг, и почему то не встретил ничего про  рекуррентную нейронную сеть, закралась мысль что с помощью этой библиотеки нельзя в принципе ее создать, как и сверточную, может я ошибаюсь ? и если  keras то чем он лучше scikit-learn?

Comment: Я тоже не нашёл ничего о RNN в sklearn. Но часто встречаются упоминания LSTM (по-моему одного из самых популярных методов RNN) метода в TensorFlow, Keras  и Theano.

Comment: @MaxU  я так понял TensorFlow самая лучшая из этих библиотек ?

Comment: Это вопрос личных предпочтений, но TensorFlow разрабатывает Google Brain Team и это говорит о многом;) PS до чего же неудобно писать с телефона да ещё и в самолёте с очень медленным WiFi :(

Comment: @MaxU спасибо за информацию, уже скачиваю книги по TensorFlow )

Comment: @MaxU и удачно долететь ))